# how to run a shell script on git commit

Tags: git, shell, testing, selenium-webdriver, casperjs

1)

i have a shell script which basically contains some(database testing and integrating test code) ,

but i have to run this shell script when ever there is commit (or any change ) in my git repo the script should execute how can i achieve this

os. Debian  6.0.1 amazon ec2

i am trying something like Travis for continues integration ..

2)

for GUI testing in Debian like O.S which is better selenium or casper.js

or is the any other beter alternative

so please help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding your first question: You are looking for the [post-commit](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks) hook.